# addEventListener Error with options in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Following the [doc page of addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), it seems it can have multiple signatures.

I want to use this one: `target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);`

However, I got a Typescript Error: `Argument of type '{ once: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.`
It seems that typescript is expecting the `target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);` signature of the fonction.

Note : Typescript 2.4.1

**my (simplified) code**

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
      // ... Stuff
    }, {once: true});
```

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "www"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Thanks.

** EDIT **

I found a workaround using `<any>{once: true}` but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `<any>{ once: true }` you can do it this way, it's the same but looks better and at least for me formats better in typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.createClickListener({ once: true });
}

createClickListener(options: any) {
  const clickTarget= document.getElementById('clickTarget');
  clickTarget.addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => this.clickHandler(),
    options
  );
}
```